# Extend MVC Application to REST

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest

I think I may have phrased the question wrong. What I have currently is an MVC Web Application that (by default) uses bearer tokens. This is all well and good but if I want to communicate with any of these APIs outside of the Web Application, I would like to use a REST client. However, I can not find a way to generate a bearer token/call the Login method and get a bearer token back to be used as an authorization header in subsequent requests.

What I hope to have:

POST /Account/Login
Returns: token

POST /Product/Create
Token Header
Body Request
Returns: success or failure

ETC. All without losing the existing functionality of the website.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: WebAPI handles tokens identically to MVC;  Where are you *actually* having issues? Are you having a problem on the client side, i.e. what to do with the bearer token returned from your endpoint?

Comment: No I think I am confused as to how to make requests to existing methods. For example, the login method that exists currently asks for a LoginModel and requires a AntiForgeryToken. This method that performs an action of redirection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/Token` endpoint already provides all the functionality you need in order to use `[Authorize]` on your WebAPI methods.  The general process to make this work would be something like the following:

1. Client establishes a POST request to `http://somesite.com/Token`.  The `Content-Type` header should contain `x-www-form-urlencoded`.  The payload body should include `grant_type=password&username="username"&password="password"`.  The `grant_type` value indicates that we are presenting a password in exchange for an access token.
2. The server response will either be a `HTTP 403` or an `HTTP 200`.  In the case of `HTTP 200`, the response body will include `access_token`, `token_type` (`bearer`), and `expires_in`.
3. The client optionally stores this `access_token` for future access, then establishes a new request to the protected server resource, including a header `Authorization`, which will be `Bearer access_token`.  This format is important, it must start with `Bearer` and a <kbd>space</kbd>, then the `access_token` value.

Note that this does not take into account issues of Cross Origin Requests (CORS), or HTTPS.  Proper security should be enacted whenever a username or password is sent, as in step 1 here.

This is configured by default on any new MVC5 project with Identity.  You will find a Startup class similar to the following:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    // Enable the application to use OAuthAuthorization. You can then secure your Web APIs
    static Startup()
    {
        PublicClientId = "web";

        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/Account/Authorize"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };
    }
```

The `TokenEndpointPath` represents your path for token requests, the `AuthorizeEndpointPath` represents the path used when External Logins (Facebook, Twitter, Google, etc.) are used.  See [this Microsoft article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/09/20/understanding-security-features-in-spa-template.aspx) for more info on the default template.

A much more detailed step by step of this process and complete client application written in Angular.js can be found on [a blog](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/) by Taiseer Joudeh.